# PHP - What is the correct way to handle this strange array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to break up this array with a foreach loop, and kind of have it working, but can't quite get what I need.

My array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 5
            [itemId] => 247
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 3
            [itemId] => 1
        )
)
```

What I want, is to loop through the above array and be able to print the following:

```
Quantity: 5
Item: 247

Quantity: 3
Item: 1
```

The problem I have is, I'm able to loop through, I just can't distinguish between the qty and itemId. It's because it's multi-dimensional and I'm clearly handling it wrong.

Here is what I have so far $idQty is my array and contains the info above:

```
foreach($idQty as $orders => $order) {
    foreach($order as $k) {
        print_r("Quantity"+$k)
    }
}
```

and what I get is everything as a Quantity. I don't know how to distinguish between the 2. Any help ?

Thanks,

Comment: What is strange about this array? ....remove the second loop and use `$order["qty"]`

Comment: Sorry, wrong use of words, just unsure how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating through the orders you'll be able to access each of the sub-arrays. You want to do it this way:

```
foreach($idQty as $index => $order) {
    echo "Quantity: " . $order['qty'];
    echo "Item: " . $order['itemId'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

u need only 1 loop

```
$idQty = array(['qty' => 5, 'itemId' => 247], ['qty' => 3, 'itemId' => 1]);
foreach ($idQty as $value) {
    print_r('Quantity:' . $value['qty'] . PHP_EOL);
    print_r('Item:' . $value['itemId'] . PHP_EOL);
}
```